# how to Call a blocking function at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading, function, blocking

I have a Class A () which will receive messages when it comes , then put it to a map .it have two methods:

1. `boolean haveResult(id)`:  return whether there are result for id
2. `String getResult(id)`:   return the result for id.

But i don't know when the message coming ,maybe 10s or 30s.

```
Class A implements MessageListener{

  private Map<String, JSONObject> resultMap = new HashMap<>();

  //receive message and put them to map
  public void onMessage(Message msg) {
     synchronized (this) {
        resultMap.put(msg.getID(),msg.getJson());
     }
  }

  public boolean haveResult(String id) {
    synchronized (this) {
        return resultMap.containsKey(id);
    }
   }

    public String getResult(String id) {
    synchronized (this) {
        JSONObject obj = resultMap.get(id);
        return obj.toString();
    }

  }
 }
```

Now, i want to send a request to the server , after the server handle bussiness handle , it will call class A method : onMessage(msg). then i want to get the message for this request (requst and response will contains same unique ID). so ,i write Class B :

```
Class B{

   function requestData(String id, String requestData){
      //send request to server
      RequestHandle.getInstance().sendRequest(id,requestData);
      while(true){
         if(!A.getInstance().haveResult(id)){
             Thread.sleep(1*1000);
         }else{
           return A.getInstance().getResult(id);
         }
      }
  }
}
```

Now the question is `B.requestData(String id, String requestData)` will be called many times at the same time,  but for every call , it must wait for the result, in other words, the function `requestData()` is blocking function.  for example,  method1 call `requestData()` maybe need 20s before get result , at the same time, method2 call `requestData()` and it maybe just need 1s before get result, but for now, method2 must wait method1 call finish, so the method2 need 20+1 = 21s ,  how to solve it?

Comment: This is very unclear.  Are class `A` and `B` running in the same JVM, or is `A` on the server and `B` on the client?

Comment: You may want to consider an entirely different design. For example, look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Comment: Class A and Class B all in client, in fact Class A messageListenr run in a new thread.

Comment: I don't see anything about `B.requestData()` that would block a concurrent call. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Are you doing some stuff that takes a long time? Put it outside the synchronized block. A complete example of your code would be useful to understand your problem.

Comment: thanks response, when Class B send request data, it must wait for server response (A will listen server response message, but server will send many different result), then B will enter "While(true){ ...}" loop util get result for it's id.

Comment: There is still nothing about `B.requesttData()` that would block a concurrent call, unless there is something about the underlying code you haven't posted that you haven't told us. But relying on a `Listener` architecture is possibly already a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use wait / notify:

```
Class A implements MessageListener{

  private Map<String, JSONObject> resultMap = new HashMap<>();

  //receive message and put them to map
  public void onMessage(Message msg) {
     synchronized (this) {
        resultMap.put(msg.getID(),msg.getJson());
        this.notifyAll();
     }
  }

  public void waitForMessage(String id) {
     synchronized (this) {        
        while(!haveResult(id) {
           try {
              this.wait();
           } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
        }
     }
  }
  ...

}
```

Class B simply calls `A.waitForMessage(id)` which will block until the message turns up.

If you're not familiar with wait / notify I suggest you read up on the topic. The [Oracle documentation is here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) but you will find many more tutorials via google.